# Work with version control Offline \ Online

Tags: offline, enterprise-architect

How can I change the status from version control work offline to working online using the API?

Can I do it to all of the model or to a particular package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, The API does not have the ability to change the version control status from offline to online or vice versa.